# Golang - create an object of the same type as passed

Tags: go, types

I'm trying to build a generic function which will parse input (in JSON) into a specified structure.  The structure may vary at run-time, based on parameters which are passed to the function.  I'm currently trying to achieve this by passing an object of the right type and using reflect.New() to create a new output object of the same type.

I'm then parsing the JSON into this object, and scanning the fields.

If I create the object and specify the type in code, everything works.  If I pass an object and try to create a replica, I get an "invalid indirect" error a few steps down (see code).

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "encoding/json"
    "strings"
)

type Test struct {
    FirstName   *string `json:"FirstName"`
    LastName    *string `json:"LastName"`
}

func genericParser(incomingData *strings.Reader, inputStructure interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    //******* Use the line below and things work *******
    //parsedInput := new(Test)


    //******* Use vvv the line below and things don't work *******
    parsedInput := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(inputStructure))

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(incomingData)
    err := decoder.Decode(&parsedInput)
    if err != nil {
        //parsing error
        return nil, err
    }

    //******* This is the line that generates the error "invalid indirect of parsedInput (type reflect.Value)" *******
    contentValues := reflect.ValueOf(*parsedInput)
    for i := 0; i < contentValues.NumField(); i++ {
        //do stuff with each field
        fmt.Printf("Field name was: %s\n", reflect.TypeOf(parsedInput).Elem().Field(i).Name)
    }
    return parsedInput, nil
}


func main() {
    inputData := strings.NewReader("{\"FirstName\":\"John\", \"LastName\":\"Smith\"}")
    exampleObject := new(Test)
    processedData, err := genericParser(inputData, exampleObject)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Parsing error")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Success: %v", processedData)
    }
}
```

If I can't create a replica of the object, then a way of updating / returning the one supplied would be feasible.  The key thing is that this function must be completely agnostic to the different structures available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reflect.New` isn't a direct analog to `new`, as it can't return a specific type, it only can return a `reflect.Value`. This means that you are attempting to unmarshal into a `*reflect.Value`, which obviously isn't going to work (even if it did, your code would have passed in `**Type`, which isn't what you want either).

Use `parsedInput.Interface()` to get the underlying value after creating the new value to unmarshal into. You then don't need to reflect on the same value a second time, as that would be a `reflect.Value` of a `reflect.Value`, which again isn't going to do anything useful.

Finally, you need to use `parsedInput.Interface()` before you return, otherwise you are returning the `reflect.Value` rather than the value of the input type.

For example:

```
func genericParser(incomingData io.Reader, inputStructure interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    parsedInput := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(inputStructure).Elem())

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(incomingData)
    err := decoder.Decode(parsedInput.Interface())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for i := 0; i < parsedInput.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Field name was: %s\n", parsedInput.Type().Elem().Field(i).Name)
    }
    return parsedInput.Interface(), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CzDrj6sgQNt